# What is index in Apache solr?

Tags: solr, lucene

I am able to upload the pdf files into `solr` and I am able to search those files. But what is indexing in `solr`? Wwhen I upload a pdf file how it will do the indexing?

This is the code I use to upload the pdf file

```
ContentStreamUpdateRequest up 
            = new ContentStreamUpdateRequest("/update/extract");

            up.addFile(fileName);

            up.setParam("literal.id", solrId);
            up.setParam("literal.first_name", "apachesolr");
            up.setParam("literal.last_name", "cookbook");
            up.setParam("literal.age", "30");

            up.setAction(AbstractUpdateRequest.ACTION.COMMIT, true, true);

            solrServer.request(up);
```

below is my `schema.xml`

```
    <field name="first_name" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>

<field name="last_name" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
<field name="age" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>

<field name="created_at" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="updated_at" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
```

when i am searching with the any content in the pdf. the result look like this

```
  SolrDocument[{
last_modified=Fri Oct 17 08:17:38 IST 2003, 
author=Mark Roth, Eduardo Pelegri-Llopart, 
title=[JSP 2.0 Specification, Final Release], 
content_type=[application/pdf], 
keywords=JSP, 
age=30, 
last_name=cookbook, 
first_name=apachesolr, 
id=jsp-2_0-fr-spec.pdf
}]
```

How it will be able to get the title, author, keywords... etc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You misunderstand concept of document in search engines. **Document** is a **set of named fields with corresponding values**. You should always explicitly set each field. To start with, try the following code with Solrj:

```
CommonsHttpSolrServer solr = new CommonsHttpSolrServer("http://localhost:8983/solr");
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
  SolrInputDocument doc = new SolrInputDocument();
  doc.addField("title", "My Favorite book");
  doc.addField("author", "Kevin");
  doc.addField("content", "Bla bla bla");
  solr.add(doc);
}
solr.commit();
```

This code creates new `SolrInputDocument` and adds 3 fields - "title", "author" and "content" (note: all these fields should be defined in schema.xml, just to let Solr know how to index and store these fields), then it adds new doc to transaction (`solr.add(doc)`) and finally commits changes. This is the basic way to work with Solr.

In this normal flow you should **extract text** from documents **yourself**. For example, you may use [Tika](http://tika.apache.org/) for this purpose. This is the most flexible and fine-grained way.

What you are trying to do is to use **new Solr feature** - **content extraction**. If I understand it correctly, you are trying to set field with `setParams()` which is wrong. `setParams()` only sets request parameters, that are then translated into URL params to let Solr know **how to handle request itself**. As far as I know, this way you cannot set fields yourself. Instead, `/update/extract` handler will try to **extract contents** by file's MIME type, **find hints about document attributes** and **use them as fields** (note that Solr uses Tika library to extract document contents). So, if you really want to use `/update/extract` handler, try to follow [this example](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ContentStreamUpdateRequestExample) **without altering** lines corresponding to request params and check **what fields where generated**.